# Pointer - 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void' to 'int'

Tags: c, pointers, void

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    void *p = &a;
    int *ptr = p; // the error occurs here (cannot convert from 'void' to 'int')
    printf("%u",*ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

the error is stated as above.
why does the error occurs?
is it because the initialization is done at the same time when the pointer is declared as void?

Comment: It is because you're trying to compile C as C++. ;)

Comment: but, if i change:
void *p = &a; into int *p = &a
it works...

Comment: @AhmadZul, Yes, because `&a` is `int *`. Why would there be a problem storing an `int *` in an `int *` and then copying it to another `int *`?

Comment: @chris : what do u mean by yes? which part...

Comment: @AhmadZul, Changing `void *` to `int *`. You've now gotten rid of your attempt to implicitly convert `void *` to `int *`.

Comment: One thing to note is that you must cast `*ptr` to `unsigned` before giving it to `printf` with `%u`. Right now, the types don't match, which is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

This is valid C but invalid C++. (C++ doesn't implicitly cast from `void*`: which is why you tend to see a lot of unnecessary casting in `malloc` in C code written by C++ programmers!)

On MSVC, rename the file to have extension `.c` and all will be well: MSVC invokes a C compiler for that extension.

Comment: Fair enough, but I suspect it will at least spill the editor with those funcy read snakes.... ;-)

Comment: No upvote but at least I'm a beer up if @alk is ever in London.

Comment: @alk, In VS2013, I get no Intellisense or compiler errors (http://i.imgur.com/2uFDhFQ.png).

Comment: You got my upvote, and I promise to add a beer to it next time, if I should ever make it onto the island again! ;-) NB: In VS10 the red-snakes are around.